# WP Sliding Bar Toggle can't close the drawer

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a custom image for my sliding bar toggle, then I have an entire Layer Slider that plays inside the drawer.

The only issue is that the close toggle is out of sight once the drawer is open, because the content in the drawer is so tall. So my first approach is I have been trying to target the selector for that close toggle, and bring it down and back into view.

I tried everything that I thought it could be, but I think it's: `.fusion-sliding-bar-position-bottom.open`

So I need to know how to get the close toggle down into view, but also:

How can I call the jQuery or whatever closes the drawer? Because you will notice, on the last slide in the drawer, I have a "Close and go back to site" button. When clicked, I want that to be able to close the drawer. I already got prepared and assigned a class to a hotspot that sits right over that button, called sb-hotpot. I can apply CSS to it, or make jQuery apply to it or whatever I need to.

*Edit: site removed - issue solved*

For now, until I can get the drawer to close, you'll obviously have to refresh the page to get out of the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

- First quesion:

You can just make the `toggle` stick to top (with `absolute` positioning), when the sliding bar is open (it has `open` class).

```
.fusion-sliding-bar-position-bottom.open .fusion-sb-toggle-wrapper {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 25px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

- Second question:

When user clicked your button, You should trigger click of `toggle` button. like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.sb-hotspot').on('click',function(e){
    $(e.target).closest('.fusion-sliding-bar-area').find('.fusion-sb-toggle') 
  [0].click();
})
});
```

Comment: @brandydoll don't put such comments or we will get banned :p

Comment: Ok I will ask you why on skype. This place is a trip.